# Adding Result Sets into One

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, resultset

I have a stored Procedure (Generate_Insert)which will output an Insert statement as output given a table name.

But Now I have created another procedure which looks like:

```
Create Procedure Inserts
As
Begin

EXEC Generate_Insert @Table = 'Admin'

EXEC Generate_Insert @Table = 'Impas'

EXEC Generate_Insert @Table = 'Asui'

EXEC Generate_Insert @Table = 'Alstd'

END
```

The sample output of

```
EXEC Generate_Insert @Table = 'Admin' is:

Insert into Admin(Ad_ID,Name,Desc) Values (1,'John','Employee')
```

The problem is when I execute this procedure I am getting result sets in different windows but i want the output as one result set.

How can I do this?

Comment: what do you mean by different windows? Are you using SSMS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the output of Generate_Insert is a varchar(max)

you can do this inside Inserts:

```
create table #temp
(
insert_stmt varchar(max)
)

insert into #temp 
EXEC Generate_Insert @Table = 'Admin'
insert into #temp 
EXEC Generate_Insert @Table = 'Impas'
insert into #temp 
EXEC Generate_Insert @Table = 'Asui'
insert into #temp 
EXEC Generate_Insert @Table = 'Alstd'

select * from #temp
```

Comment: Perfect this is what I want exactly. Thank you so much!